# Python mutliprocessing: Timestamp of a process

Tags: python, timestamp, multiprocessing

I am using python multiprocessing module. I need to see the timestamp at which a process starts and the timestamp at which a process ends. If I do this:

```
    ...
    processes = [Process(target=topo.func1, args=(host,servers,q)) for x in range(1,i)]
    for p in processes:
     p.start()
     print p 
     <Process(Process-1, started)>

     p.join()
     print p
     <Process(Process-1, stopped)>
```

It only prints process number and status. How can I print the timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**import datetime** module first and then you can print the timestamp

Comment: You have to read the time `datetime.datetime.now()` explicitely when you start the process and the same when you stopped the process. Even if the OS does keep information on when the process was started I don't think it will store the time when it has been terminated, so you have to do that for yourself anyway.